# Can I check in unit test, that some method was called 2 times? How?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, bpmn, camunda

I have BPMN-project and use Camunda.

I have delegate class, which checks duplicate existence of the process with the same journey code and status:

```java
@Component
public class CheckIsDuplicateDepartedJourneyProcessedDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
  @Override
  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    String currentProcessInstanceId = execution.getProcessInstanceId();
    String journeyCode = DelegateExecutionUtils.getStringVariable(execution, JOURNEY_CODE);
    String journeyStatus = DelegateExecutionUtils.getStringVariable(execution, TRIP_STATUS);
    boolean hasDuplicate =
        execution
            .getProcessEngine()
            .getRuntimeService()
            .createProcessInstanceQuery()
            .processDefinitionKey(UPDATE_JOURNEY_STATUS_PROCESS_ID)
            .processInstanceBusinessKey(journeyCode)
            .variableValueEquals(TRIP_STATUS, journeyStatus)
            .list()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(process -> !process.getProcessInstanceId().equals(currentProcessInstanceId));
    execution.setVariable(DUPLICATE_PROCESS, hasDuplicate);
  }
}
```

How can I check in unit-test, that method execute(...) or execution.getProcessInstanceId() was called 2 times (1 time in every of 2 processes)? I need check that 2 processes worked and want to track down that some of method mentioned in delegate was called once per process (2 in 2 processes).

My current unit-test. It works bad, because says, that method execute(...) was not called.

```java
public class UpdateJourneyStatusProcessTest extends BaseTest {

  @Spy private CheckIsDuplicateDepartedJourneyProcessedDelegate checkDelegate = new CheckIsDuplicateDepartedJourneyProcessedDelegate();
   ...
    // when
    sender.send(firstCommand); // recieving this command initiates process and delegate work
    sender.send(secondCommand);

    // then
    verify(checkDelegate, times(2)).execute(any(DelegateExecution.class)); // says that method was called 0 times
    ...

  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Updated answer. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the best approach would be to setup a single process and check that DUPLICATE_PROCESS is not set.

Then setup an additional (duplicate) process, call your method, then check for your DUPLICATE_PROCESS is set.

I am not sure I understand all the details but I am assuming you can start these processes by direct invocation of a command.

Comment: Yes, I start my process via command sending and when camunda get the command it starts the process.

In mentioned case I'm afraid while I check DUPLICATE_PROCESS and initiate second process, the first process can be completed and DUPLICATE_PROCESS will be false. That's why I send 2 commands together.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running a plain Java test or a Spring test?

The process engine will resolve the delegate as you have specified in the process model. If you process model is referencing a Java Class then it will instantiate that class no matter what. If you are using a Delegate expression then you are referencing a Spring bean by name.
Since you are instantiating CheckIsDuplicateDepartedJourneyProcessedDelegate in your test, I assume it is not a Spring test, but plain Java. In a plain Java test you would have to make sure that Camunda can resolve the bean name. This is done using Mocks.register(...). Have you registered your @spy bean under the bean name use in the Delegate expression in the process mdoel?

I would not use a delegate but an expression, then not check it on delegate level at all, but check if the two process instances follow the desired paths using normal asserts, e.g. `assertThat(pi).hasPassed("somewhere").isWaitingAt("someTask");`

Here is an example model including an expression which can be used to implement Singleton behavior. You can adjust the expression along the lines shown in your delegate implementation.

https://github.com/rob2universe/process-models/blob/798c2097fffc330be7dc498f0354b02dc32410c6/bpmn/singleton.bpmn#L15

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted is incomplete, so I am not sure if one important step for this to work is done or not. Maybe that is the problem.

To check if `execute(...)` was called - The `sender` object should have the mocked object - `checkDelegate`. 
Or 
To check if `execution.getProcessInstanceId()` was called - You should create a mock of `DelegateExecution execution` and set it in the `checkDelegate` object.

You can pass it through the constructor or set it after initialization in your UnitTest.